# Scylla logs in CentOS and RedHat

Tags: cassandra, scylla

We have installed open source scylla on redhat linux. After installation checking the logs but not able to find system.log file. In cassandra there is file called system.log where all logs are stored. but in scylla I can not see any log file. However I have configured the path in logback.xml.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scylla logs are written to the system journal.
Use the following to get them:

```
journalctl _COMM=scylla
```

More here https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/logging/